# How should I organize song download links of movies in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, data-management

I am asking in general how should I organize data in database.

Say I have 5 movies and each movie has 5 songs and it's download link.

So should I
- Make table for each movie and add song name and it's download link in that table like:

```
+-------------------------------+
|          Movie Name           |
+-------------------------------+
| SongTitle         varchar()   |
| DownloadLink varchar()        |
+-------------------------------+
```

or
- Make one table that contains movie name, song title and it's download link like:

```
+-------------------------------------+
|         Song Database               |
+-------------------------------------+
| MovieName            varchar()      |
| SongName             varchar()      |
| DownloadLink         varchar()      |
+-------------------------------------+
```

Which way will provide better management of data and take less time to load?

How to decide when to create a separate table and when to use the same table for all the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Movies and songs can exist independently:

```
movies (movie_id PK, movie_name)
songs (song_id PK, song_name, download_link)
```

How to associate them depends on your need.  If movies can have multiple songs, but each song can belong to only one movie:

```
movie_songs (song_id PK/FK, movie_id FK)
```

But if songs can be used in multiple movies, then:

```
movie_songs (song_id PK/FK, movie_id PK/FK)
```